# In the IPv6(NAT64) environment,networkStream.BeginRead does't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcpclient, netstream

The following code works well in IPV4,And,In the IPv6(NAT64) environment,it can connect the server and send message success,It can capture the data from server, But,the callback **OnRead** never be executed.

It's been bothering me for a long time.

```
private TcpClient client = null;
private const int MAX_READ = 8192;
private NetworkStream outStream = null;
private byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[MAX_READ];


public void ConnectServerByIP(string ip, int port) {

    client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6);


    client.SendTimeout = 1000;
    client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
    client.NoDelay = true;

    IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);

    try {
        client.BeginConnect(ipAddr, port, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Close(); Debug.LogError(e.Message);
    }

}

void OnConnect(IAsyncResult asr) {
    outStream = client.GetStream();

    client.GetStream ().BeginRead (byteBuffer, 0, MAX_READ,new  AsyncCallback(OnRead), null);

    NetworkManager.AddEvent(Protocal.Connect, new ByteBuffer());
}

void OnRead(IAsyncResult asr) {
    Debug.Log ("Hello~");
}
```

Comment: It would probably help if you `EndConnect` so that you can pick up any exceptions, etc.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145193(v=vs.110).aspx): "The asynchronous **BeginConnect operation must be completed** by calling the EndConnect method. Typically, the method is invoked by the asyncCallback delegate."